# Creating lists in python, if statement syntax error

Tags: python, list

I'm creating a project that has two lists of popular boy and girl names. it instructs the user to enter a boy a girl name and then lets them know if that name was popular. I'm pretty sure I have everything right, but I keep on getting a syntax error in line 18 (elif statement under if gender == 'g'), highlighting the colon after elif. If anyone has any idea why that would be very helpful because i can't figure it out

```
def main():
    # Open a file for reading.
    infile = open('GirlNames.txt', 'r')
    infile2 = open('BoyNames.txt', 'r')

    # Read the contents of the file into a list.
    GirlNames = infile.readlines()
    BoyNames = infile2.readlines()

    # Close the file.
    infile.close()

    gender = input('Enter g to search for a girl name, b for a boys name, or both for both')
    if gender == 'g':
        girl = input('Please enter a girls name: ')
        if girl in GirlNames:
            print (girl, "was a popular girl's name between 2000 and 2009")
        elif: 
            print (girl, "was not a popular girl's name between 2000 and 2009")
    if gender == 'b':
        boy = input('Please enter a boys name: ')
        if boy in BoyNames:
            print (boy, "was a popular boy's name between 2000 and 2009")
        elif:
            print (boy, "was not a popular boy's name between 2000 and 2009")
    elif gender == 'both':
        girl1 = input("Please enter a girl's name ")
        boy1 = input("please enter a boy's name ")
        if girl1 in GirlNames:
            print (girl1, "was a popular girl's name between 2000 and 2009")
        if boy1 in BoyNames:
            print (boy1, "was a popular boy's name between 2000 and 2009")


# Call the main function.
main()
```

Comment: Change `elif` to `else`. You would need to add an argument after `elif` for it to work. For example `elif girl not in GirlNames:` would also work.

Comment: `elif:` is not valid syntax.

Comment: `elif:` is missing its argument, same as you have given conditional arguments for `if ...` clauses, `elif ...` should have something in `...` as its argument also

Comment: Thank you that worked! However, even when I enter a name that is in GirlNames or BoyNames, it still prints that it was not a popular name. I have both text files downloaded to the same file that the program is in so I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Maybe ensure you are comparing similar case strings, usually convert all strings to same-case (lowercase or uppercase) before comparison, try something like this: `if girl.lower() in [g.lower() for g in GirlNames]:`

Comment: I use `switch-case` statements when several conditions are involved. It will make your code cleaner and easy to maintain as well.

Comment: In addition to the answers about `elif`, `GirlNames` and `BoyNames` will both have newlines at the end of each name. So, the name from your prompt will never be in either list. You need to `rstrip('\n')` for each name int the 2 lists.